# Flutter need to pass a List between screens

Tags: flutter

I have very simple list like this

```
{
            "OrderID": 208,
            "CustomerID": 2,
            "TransactionNo": 80,
            "OrderNo": 1,
 
            "OrderCheckouts": {
                "OrderCheckoutID": 207,
                "OrderID": 208,
                "PaymentMode": 1,
                "AmountPaid": 17.3,
                "AmountTotal": 17.3,
  
            },
}
```

I need to pass it through screen so i am passing like this

```
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>
                                    OrderDetails(text: posts.data[position])
                            ),
                          );
                        },
```

And in other screen getting data like this

```
class OrderDetails extends StatefulWidget {


  final List text;

  // receive data from the FirstScreen as a parameter
  OrderDetails({Key key, @required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OrderDetailsState createState() => _OrderDetailsState();
}
```

Its showing error `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'`

I try like this also   `final List<String, dynamic> text;` But not working can any please tell how can i pass it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have the single Object of type Map<String, Dynamic> (Kind of JSON Data), and want to assign it in List.

For handling the Json data try to make the Model Class then send the object of that model class as a reference.

Here are some Resources -:

1. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ega4EG8ZVM4

Maybe it will help you out

Answer (score 0):

*posts.data[position]* is a *_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>*

Can you try define ?:

```
Map<String, dynamic> text;
```